# EXC_BAD_ACCESS after NSWindowWillCloseNotification removes window from Array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

Say I have a menu button called 'Create window' that creates a new window:

```
MyWindowClass * window = [MyWindowClass new];
```

In order to retain it, I add it to a mutable array (declared and synthesised as _articleArray = [NSMutableArray new];)

```
[_articleArray addObject:window]
```

This works great. If I include:

```
NSLog(@"Windows in mem: %lu",_articleArray.count);
```

The number increments each time that I click the button and another window appears on the screen.

Now, if I attach a selector to this 'create window' function to identify when the window closes:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowClosed:) name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification object:window];
```

This creates an error:

```
-(void) windowClosed:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [_articleArray removeObject:[notification object]];
    NSLog(@"Windows in mem: %lu",_articleArray.count);
```

The NSLog decrements when I close a window as expected, but as soon as the function ends, it throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (code 13, address=0,0)

```
0x7fff97878710:  movq   24(%rax), %rax
```

I am very confused. The number decrements, so I can only think that the function is working. So what is happening here?

EDIT: (lldb) thread backtrace

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c07, 0x00007fff97878710 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend_vtable13 + 16, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, address=0x0)
frame #0: 0x00007fff97878710 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend_vtable13 + 16
frame #1: 0x00007fff97571503 Foundation`__NSFireTimer + 80
frame #2: 0x00007fff993a6da4 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
frame #3: 0x00007fff993a68bd CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 557
frame #4: 0x00007fff9938c099 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1513
frame #5: 0x00007fff9938b6b2 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
frame #6: 0x00007fff8df260a4 HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
frame #7: 0x00007fff8df25e42 HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
frame #8: 0x00007fff8df25cd3 HIToolbox`BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
frame #9: 0x00007fff92ce3613 AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 685
frame #10: 0x00007fff92ce2ed2 AppKit`-[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
frame #11: 0x00007fff92cda283 AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 517
frame #12: 0x00007fff92c7ecb6 AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 869
frame #13: 0x0000000100006942 myApp`main + 34 at main.m:13
frame #14: 0x00007fff9094f7e1 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: Once you've added the window object to the array you can release it, as the array will retain it.  If you aren't using ARC, you will get a memory leak.  Also you need to remove the observer from the window in your notification method.

Comment: @trojanfoe There is no stack-trace in the output window, just (lldb) and then the EXC_BAD_ACCESS line that I highlighted above shows up in the main editor window. I am using ARC, so not solution A, but removing the observer seems like it may be the issue - I can't quite work out how at the moment, will keep trying but could you perhaps help me out a little, how I'd go about it?

Comment: In the debugger console, typing `thread backtrace` (assuming lldb) should print the stacktrace that will be useful to continue this.

Comment: @trojanfoe Wow! that is really useful (or will be when I learn to understand it!) I have appended the original post with the backtrace. Thankyou so much for taking your time to help.

Comment: Hmmm, the trace isn't that revealing.  It's based off some timer event by look of it.  Did you say that if you remove the notification from the window, it no longer crashes?

Comment: @trojanfoe Correct, also, if I don't remove the item from the array: aka, comment out the instruction: ([_articleArray removeObject:windowToRemove];) it doesn't crash. But it also doesn't remove the object from memory :p

Comment: Sounds like the problem is solved then?

Comment: @trojanfoe Quite the opposite, when the window is closed, it should be released from memory, hence I am trying to remove it from the array which is retaining it. (furthermore I am trying to keep a count of windows, so _articleArray.count needs to be maintained). This is very odd behaviour, I will keep trying - If you think of anything else then please let me know.

Comment: Is the window `isReleasedWhenClosed == YES`?

Comment: It was! Now it's not and its completely fixed! If you reply to this question with this as answer then i'll mark it as correct. Thank you so, so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer has been moved from the comments in the question at the request of the OP*

You need to ensure that you remove your `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` observer before the window is destroyed:

```
-(void) windowClosed:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSWindow *window = [notification object];
    [[NotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                  name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification
                                                object:window];
    [_articleArray removeObject:window];
    NSLog(@"Windows in mem: %lu",_articleArray.count);
    ...
```

And also ensure that the window has its `isReleasedWhenClosed` property set to `YES` so that it cleans-up after itself when closed.